# How to create an object in Custom properties using groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

i'm new in soapui and groovy.
i'm trying to create an object in Custom Properties, the value of the object is already retrived with a groovy code from json response after a first request.

How can i create the object in Custom Properties?

Here is the first Groovy code which extract the value of "id" from the json response:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Request_1").getPropertyValue("response")
slurperresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)
log.info (slurperresponse.id)
```

Output:

```
INFO:100
```

I tried this:

```
def Id = context.expand('${Id#Id}')    
context.getTestCase().setPropertyValue('Id', Id);
```

The value of the variable "Id" in Custom Properties of the TestCase is empty
What i was expecting is to get Id=100

THank you

Comment: Since you are new to Groovy **and** SoapUI, why not just start using the built-in SoapUI stuff? Like property transfer? http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/transferring-property-values.html

Comment: i have the soapui open source version not the pro versiob

Comment: Property transfer step is **not** a -Pro feature!

Comment: Thanks a lot i resolved my problem with Property step, i used Groovy